# 400 Bad Request error using ingest/fastingest on EchoPrint

Tags: python, audio-fingerprinting, echoprint

I am doing the following to start codegen/ server for echo print !

```
cd echoprint-server/solr/solr
java -Dsolr.solr.home=/home/path/to/echoprint-server/solr/solr/solr/ -
Djava.awt.headless=true -jar start.jar

ttservctl start

python api.py 9090
```

Ingest codes are at http://pastebin.com/8iud70hD

```
curl http://localhost:9090/ingest -d
"fp_code=<fp_code_here>&track_id=thisone&length=30000"
```

I am getting the following error --

```
127.0.0.1:40197 - - [01/Jul/2011 18:06:33] "HTTP/1.1 POST /ingest" - 400 Bad Request
```

Comment: What's up with fp_code=[nothing]? Looks funky to me.

Comment: sorry for that, its a really big code that I wanted to avoid putting here, i had written <fo_code> and somehow it vanished after formatting !

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to ingest a very long code? length=30000?

Think the api calls are not capable to handle too long codes, so i used the python calls directly. You should try to follow this instruction:

https://github.com/echonest/echoprint-server#generating-and-importing-data